# How to make LAMP LDAPS authentication work?

Tags: linux, authentication, centos, ldap, lamp

We have been struggling for months trying to enable the LDAS connection with our LAMP application. Its an internal server and we don´t need any special cypher but just accessing to LDAPS port.

```
lampstack-7.2.26-0

Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

PHP 5.4.16

OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips
```

Current .htaccess config that works ok with LDAP:

```
AuthType               Basic
AuthName               "Login with your Company ID"
AuthBasicProvider      ldap
AuthLDAPURL            "ldap://xxx/DC=xx,DC=x,DC=grp?sAMAccountName"
AuthLDAPBindDN         "svc-apache-ldap-auth"
AuthLDAPBindPassword   "<password>"
AuthLDAPCompareAsUser  on
LDAPReferrals          off

Require ldap-group CN=sxx,OU=xx,OU=Services,OU=Groups,OU=Enterprise,DC=xx,DC=x,DC=xx
```

From the client we can successfully do the ldapsearch test from root user with both LDAP and LDAPs

```
as root user:

ldapsearch -ZZ  --> OK

ldapsearch (unsecured) --> OK

with domain user:

ldapsearch -ZZ  --> ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)

ldapsearch (unsecured) --> OK
```

One possible issue could be a permissions one? LAMP uses the "daemon" especial user to run the services.

We have tried many things. The most obvious is to add the "s" to

AuthLDAPURL            "ldap://xxx/DC=xx,DC=x,DC=grp?sAMAccountName"

Like this

AuthLDAPURL            "ldap**s**://xxx/DC=xx,DC=x,DC=grp?sAMAccountName"

When we try that, we get a 500 error at the webpage and this message in the logs

```
AH01695: auth_ldap authenticate: user XXX authentication failed; URI / [LDAP: ldap_set_option failed.Could not set LDAP_OPT_X_TLS to LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_HARD][Can't contact LDAP server]
```

We also try adding

TLS_CRLCHECK none

TLS_REQCERT never

to the ldap.conf files but the same error appears.

Other things have been tried but I have just put the most relevant ones. Not sure what else to try to get working LDAPS

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: It was finally fixed by using a different Lamp Stack version 7.4.30-1
Seems that version 7.2.26-0 had this bug that LDAPS was not working.